# Is there a limit to the number of inputs/outputs states during transaction building?

Tags: corda

On Corda Open Source 3.2 with postgres 9.6. I have 300 obligations states in the transaction that has to atomically transition to `SETTLED` **AND** cash states as inputs to knock these obligations off.

I am getting a pagination error during `recordTransactions`. Is there a limit to how many states that can be put into a transaction?

Stacktrace below

```
[ERROR] 2018-08-10T06:40:38,702Z [Node thread-1] flow.[a80ddfb6-628e-4194-98ef-77261512b6fb].call - Error during mutedTry  {}
net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException: Please specify a `PageSpecification` as there are more results [201] than the default page size [200]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy(NodeVaultService.kt:426) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.loadStates(NodeVaultService.kt:546) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.access$loadStates(NodeVaultService.kt:49) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService$makeUpdates$1.invoke(NodeVaultService.kt:143) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.makeUpdates(NodeVaultService.kt:188) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.access$makeUpdates(NodeVaultService.kt:49) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService$notifyAll$1.invoke(NodeVaultService.kt:119) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.notifyAll(NodeVaultService.kt:130) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.recordTransactions(ServiceHubInternal.kt:118) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl$recordTransactions$1.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:857) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl$recordTransactions$1.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:818) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:136) ~[corda-node-api-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:124) ~[corda-node-api-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:131) ~[corda-node-api-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.recordTransactions(AbstractNode.kt:856) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.recordTransactions(ServiceHub.kt:201) ~[corda-core-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.recordTransactions(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.recordTransactions(AbstractNode.kt:818) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.recordTransactions(ServiceHub.kt:193) ~[corda-core-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.recordTransactions(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.recordTransactions(AbstractNode.kt:818) ~[corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.notariseAndRecord(FinalityFlow.kt:78) ~[corda-core-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:56) ~[corda-core-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:28) ~[corda-core-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at example.template.flows.SettleOblgiations$Initiator.call(SettleOblgiations.kt:105) ~[obligation-1.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.2.1847-corda.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you perform a vault query returning over 200 results, you need to provide a `PageSpecification` to define how the results are returned. This is to prevent memory overflow errors if too many results are returned. Here is an example of a vault query using a `PageSpecification`:

```
val vaultSnapshot = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ContractState>(
    criteria = VaultQueryCriteria(UNCONSUMED),
    paging = PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, 200))
```

`FinalityFlow` calls out to `NodeVaultService.loadStates`, which is where your error is being thrown. As of Corda 3.2, `NodeVaultService.loadStates` is not doing anything to prevent it requesting more than 200 results at once, causing the pagination error to be thrown. This has been fixed in `master` and the fix will be included in Corda 3.3/Corda 4, as follows:

```
private fun loadStates(refs: Collection<StateRef>): Collection<StateAndRef<ContractState>> {
    val states = mutableListOf<StateAndRef<ContractState>>()
    if (refs.isNotEmpty()) {
        val refsList = refs.toList()
        val pageSize = PageSpecification().pageSize
        (0..(refsList.size - 1) / pageSize).forEach {
            val offset = it * pageSize
            val limit = minOf(offset + pageSize, refsList.size)
            val page = queryBy<ContractState>(QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(stateRefs = refsList.subList(offset, limit))).states
            states.addAll(page)
        }
    }
    return states
}
```

Comment: Hmm I would understand if the error is thrown from my query. But the exception is from Finality Flow?

Comment: Ah, sorry. This appears to be a bug. Updated my answer above.

Comment: This error is from OpenSource 3.2. Do you know if the same behaviour is exhibited on enterprise?

Comment: The behaviour is the same on Enterprise. But it's odd - as the code does clearly try to only grab a certain number of results (less than the page size) at once. Something is not working as intended.

Comment: Replicated here, the test ran quite slow on my machine (during collectSignature), took awhile for the responder to sign maybe due to large tx, but at the end will throw the same exact error. https://github.com/adrian-soon/obligation-cordapp/blob/finality-pagination/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/ManyObligationsTests.kt

Comment: This has been fixed in `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this issue.
It has indeed been fixed on master since May, and will be included in the next OS 3.3 release.
See https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3788